# View control through boolean short-circuiting

Tags: reactjs, react-native, short-circuiting

I came across an example like this when I was learning React Native:

```js
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showView: true,
    }
  }

  removeView(){
     this.setState({
       showView: false,
     });
  }

  render(){
    return (
       <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
       {this.state.showView && (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100 }}> // View to be removed
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.removeView()}>
                  <Text>Remove View</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
       )}
       </View>
    )
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is why the View can be controlled by `this.state.showView` this way, I'm sure it definitely has to do with boolean short-circuiting, but I think the content in the brackets should evaluate to a boolean value, so I should only be able to a true/false value on the component instead of seeing the content of the View. Can somebody explain a bit more about why it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to React documentation:

> It works because in JavaScript, `true && expression` always evaluates to
>   `expression`, and `false && expression` always evaluates to `false`.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is `true`, the element right after `&&` will
>   appear in the output. If it is `false`, React will ignore and skip it.